# ¿Cuál es mi fallo en este programa de python hecho con tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy aprendiendo a programar con python y actualmente estoy con tkinter. Estoy intentando tener dos frames dentro de la raiz, uno a la izquierda y otro a la derecha, y en el de la izquierda, añadir tres entries, pero al correrlo no sale como yo espero:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as tkMessageBox
from tkinter.tix import *
import functools

raiz=Tk()

raiz.config(bg="red",pady=10,padx=10,width=200,height=200)

ventana1 = Frame (raiz, bg="blue").grid(sticky="nsew")



nombre = Entry(ventana1)

nombre.grid(column=0,row=0,padx=20,pady=20)

clave = Entry (ventana1)

clave.grid(column=0,row=1,padx=20,pady=20)

antiguedad = Entry (ventana1)

antiguedad.grid(column=0,row=2,padx=20,pady=20)

ventana2= Frame (raiz, bg="#F1EF32",width=100,height=300). grid(column=1,columnspan=3, row=0,sticky="nsew",padx=10,pady=10)




raiz.mainloop()
```

El frame de la izquierda sólo cubre el primer entry, los demás no parece que estén contenidos en ese frame.

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUCION**

Crea el Frame y ubícalo en líneas separadas tal y como se muestra en el código de abajo.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as tkMessageBox
from tkinter.tix import *
import functools

raiz=Tk()

raiz.config(bg="red",pady=10,padx=10,width=200,height=200)

ventana1 = Frame (raiz, bg="blue")
ventana1.grid(sticky="nsew")



nombre = Entry(ventana1)
nombre.grid(column=0,row=0,padx=20,pady=20)

clave = Entry (ventana1)
clave.grid(column=0,row=1,padx=20,pady=20)

antiguedad = Entry (ventana1)
antiguedad.grid(column=0,row=2,padx=20,pady=20)


ventana2= Frame (raiz, bg="#F1EF32",width=100,height=300)
ventana2.grid(column=1,columnspan=3, row=0,sticky="nsew",padx=10,pady=10)



raiz.mainloop()
```

**EXPLICACION**

Cuando creas el frame y llamas a .grid, el valor que se devuelve es None. Entonces decir `ventana1 = Frame (raiz, bg="blue").grid(sticky="nsew")` es como decir `ventana1 = None`.
None es la forma que tiene tkinter para referirse al valor default. Entonces, por default los entrys no se crean en el Frame, sino en la ventana raiz.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias!